# Changing query params placeholder format in query string

Tags: jooq

Calling `query.getSQL(ParamType.NAMED)` returns a query string with params placeholders in format `:1, :2, :3::myenum` etc. Since I am mixing jooq with vert.x, I am looking for a way to represent params placeholders in a format using `$` instead of colon: `$1, $2, $3`, which will be more elegant than force replacing on each query creation. Is there any way to manage this through jooq configuration or by any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`Settings.renderNamedParamPrefix`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderNamedParamPrefix)